# DOM is not updated with EventListener using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wkwebview, addeventlistener

Context : I'm using an Angular PWA to communicate with an iOS native application through WKWebview. I'm using messageHandlers to be able to share data between typescript files and the Swift logic code.

Problem : I'm using addEventListener to listen a specific event on the window object. From my component, I subscribe to an observable to listen the change. But my component doesn't apply variable changes inside the subscribe method.

**myService.ts**

```
public myValue$ = new Subject<number>();

window.addEventListener('didDeviceDisconnected', (e) => {
     ...
     this.dispatchInfo(someInfo);
});

private dispatchInfo(value: number) {
     this.myValue$.next(value);
}

public getValue(): Observable<number> {
     return this.myValue$.asObservable();
}
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
// Wait for the notification
this.myValueSubscription = this.myService.getValue().subscribe(value => {
     this.myValue = value;
     alert("myValue : " + this.myValue);
})
```

**myComponent.html**

```
{{ myValue }}
```

The alert displays correctly the value but the DOM shows that the value is undefined. I also tried to add setTimeout inside the subscribe function without success. How can I apply the change from the subscribe method ? Is it outside the angular scope ?

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is really what you think it is? What if you `console.log(this)` just above the `alert`? My guess is, `this` refers to `window`, not to your component, therefore `this.myValue` actually is `window.myValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) which provides change detection functionality.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(..,  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

this.myValueSubscription = this.myService.getValue().subscribe(value => {
    this.myValue = value;
    alert("myValue : " + this.myValue);

    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <= ADDED
})
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it is  outside the angular scope.

you can try this..

**myComponent.ts**

```
import { Component , NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

......

```
constructor(public ngZone: NgZone)
```

......

```
this.myValueSubscription = this.myService.getValue().subscribe(value => {
    this.ngZone.run(()=> {
          this.myValue = value;
        });
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same behavior even if I think this is a correct approach